# Alternatives to freestyle and grease pencil when using panoramic cameras? For full-dome rendering. Cycles only <3

Tags: cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil, freestyle, panoramic, fisheye

I'm working on a full dome project, rendering in Cycles with a fisheye equidistant camera with a 210d FoV angle.

Since freestyle and grease pencil are not supported with panoramic cameras (please let me know if I'm wrong) I'm looking for an alternative method that would allow me to achieve a similar 2D line-drawing effect - like freestyle and grease pencil would work when using a perspective camera.

Example with fisheye lens:
[image]
I'm getting the lines but they are rendered as if I was using a perspective camera... How could I get those line warped so they match the scene's content?

Example with perspective cam:
[image]
This image is just a reference to showcase how freestyle works with perspective cams.

Any leads on this are more than welcome <3

Comment: What I would like to know is what your full dome project is? Will your image be stretched out to be a 360-degree view or are you just trying to make a 2d image with a panoramic distortion.